# Loading .js file cross domain using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a cross domain .js file using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    crossDomain:true,
    url: "http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp'    
}).done(callback);
```

I have a callback at the moment:

```
getBootStrapperScript(function (callback) {         
       //do somethibg
})
```

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js. Origin http://localhost:62607 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have been reading about JSONP but I'm not sure how to use it to load a .js file from anoather domain.

If I change the above code to use 'jsonp' for the datatype but I then get this errer:

```
GET http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js?callback=jQuery18206067646441515535_1354459693160&_=1354459696966 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I load cross domain js files?

Comment: looks like you are victim of same origin policy

Comment: This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis

Comment: There's a special function that does this for you, it's called [**$.getScript()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), and it get's the external javascript file and inserts it. An other way would be to look at how Google does it with stuff like the analytics file, inserting a script tag into the head, and do something like that. Using an Ajax call with jsonp is **NOT** the way to do it.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Genuinely interested so I can provide better questions in future :)

Comment: Thanks all - see comment on Darins answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use any AJAX, simply use the [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function:

```
$.getScript('http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js').done(callback);
```

As you know, you could be pointing the `<script>` tag to any domain you wish without violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). That's the basis of JSONP. But you don't need any JSONP, because all you need is to reference a script form a remote domain, which is as simple as pointing the `<script>` tag to this script or if you want to do it dynamically use the `$.getScript` function that jQuery has to offer you.

---

UPDATE:

The `$.getScript` function will append a random cache busting parameter to the url. If you want to get a cached version of your script you could define a custom `cachedScript`  function as shown in the documentation:

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function(url, options) {
    options = $.extend(options || {}, {
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        url: url
    });
    return jQuery.ajax(options);
};
```

and then:

```
$.cachedScript('http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js').done(callback);
```

Comment: thanks, I still get the error:   GET http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js?_=1354460928278 404 (Not Found). :(

Comment: What happens when you type `http://localhost/62588/scripts/bootStrapper.js?_=1354460928278` in your browser address bar? Is the script served? Or do you get 404? If the script is served without an error I would be greatly surprised. If you get 404, well, then, make sure you have provided a correct url to your script in the $.getScript function - one that actually exists on your server at the specified address :-)

Comment: yeah, 404 but with only http://localhost:62588/Scripts/bootStrapper.js - the script is served.

Comment: Weird, your web server doesn't serve the script if there are query string parameters? The `_=1354460928278` bit is to ensure that you get a fresh version of the script from the server. If you don't want this random query string parameter to be appended to the url you could set the `cache: false` parameter. Read the documentation of the `$.getScript` function I've linked to in my answer. There's a section called `Caching Responses` at the end. Look at the example provided there. They define a custom `jQuery.cachedScript` function. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Actually - I'm an idiot:  Real reason - look at the url: $.getScript('http://localhost/62588/ the '/' after localhost should actually be a ':'  - thanks Darin.