# Calling WCF service from jQuery in asp.net

Tags: wcf, jquery

I'm trying to call a WCF service using jQuery in asp.net

WCF service and asp.net website is under the same solution, however they run in different ports as below

```
 WCF - http://127.0.0.1:54443/Service1.svc/
 asp.net - http://127.0.0.1:57484/WebSite2/
```

Below is the WCF function code

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        public List<string> getCurrentTime()
        {
            List<string> lstrSampleDate = new List<string>();
            lstrSampleDate.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
            return lstrSampleDate;
        }
```

and below is jquery code

```
 $.ajax({

                 type: "GET",
                 url: "http://127.0.0.1:54443/Service1.svc/getCurrentTime",
                 // crossDomain: true,
                 datatype: "json",
                 success: function (rVal) {
                     //console.log
                     alert(rVal);
                 },
                 error: function (xhr, status) {
                     //console.log
                     alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText + 'Status: ' + xhr.status);
                 },
                 complete: function (xhr, status) {
                     //console.log
                     alert("The request is completed!");
                 }
             });
```

When i execute the code i get the below error get printed in console

> ```
> > XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> > http://127.0.0.1:54443/Service1.svc/getCurrentTime. Origin
> > http://127.0.0.1:57484 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> ```

As a work-around i did add the below settings to config file (of website)

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and still did get any fruitful result.  can anyone point me where i'm missing?

Note: I've replaced 'localhost' with 127.0.0.1
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll find this post helpful: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error sending a jQuery Post to Google API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis)

> I solved the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error **modifying the dataType
>   parameter to dataType:'jsonp' and adding a crossDomain:true**