# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http

Tags: javascript, tomcat

I am a beginner at the web applications realm and I'm trying to build a simple web site that sends an `httprequest` (with javascript `XMLHttpRequest` object).
the web page (html) sits on an "HTTP Preview at localhost" server
and the servlet sits on another server "Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost"

When I try to send the http request I get the next error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9999/ebookshop/querymp?author=Tan+Ah+Teck&price=50. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin > 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My guess is that it happens because I'm trying to access another server but I don't know how to solve it. On eclipse's browser I see the result and that works fine.

Comment: looking like CORS(Cross Origin) issue.

Comment: is it a service that you are calling???    Put this -->> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *   ,  in your header and it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS on the server in your case localhost is the one.
 you need to have this on request header

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9999`

Answer (score 0):

So adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" helped..
But it doesn't seems right having 2 different servers e.g:
1.HTTP Preview at localhost
2.Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

Is there a way combining the "Http Preview server" with the Tomcat server?
or it is unnecessary?

Answer (score -2):

Answers to your Question are here

[ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Very important if you do not have idea about this
[Works for jQuery and Not for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)