# Stop page from redirecting after submitting google form through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm using AJAX and a google spreadsheet to collect email data for a newsletter by taking the POST data from a form field and sending it to the spreadsheet through google forms. I can't get the code to stop the page from redirecting to google's thank you page. This is the AJAX and form code below.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1TEPXPqigGuN8sayYjz-sk6H-5wAbPaImsgadM2PBFAk/formResponse" method="POST" id="newsletter-form" target="_self" onsubmit="">
    <input type="text" name="entry_291075079" value="" class="form-control" id="Email" dir="auto" placeholder="example@site.com"> 
</form>

<script>
    $("#newsletter-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1TEPXPqigGuN8sayYjz-sk6H-5wAbPaImsgadM2PBFAk/formResponse",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Submission successful');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Submission failed: ' + error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Instantiate a new window, run Ajax, terminate new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is being redirected because it is doing a standard form submission via POST - your javascript code is not attached to the form submission at all. To do what you require you could attach the JS code to the `submit` event of the form, and stop the submission by using `preventDefault()`, something like this:

```
<script>
    $('#ss-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "url to google form responses",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Submission successful');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Submission failed: ' + error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but when using $('#ss-form').submit(e) {, I get an error for that line. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" Any idea why?

Comment: That got rid of the error, but it's still redirecting to the google success page.

Comment: You need to remove it from the `postContactToGoogle()` function and attach it on the `submit` event using jQuery, exactly as in my answer.

Comment: Ok, did that, I got this error in the console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1TEPXPqigGuN8sayYjz-sk6H-5wAbPaImsgadM2PBFAk/formResponse. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
index.html:93 Submission failed:"

Comment: Excellent, that means the request is now being sent. For how to resolve the new problem, please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis)