# simple ajax POST with cross domain request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, cross-domain

I am trying to send a simple form with only one parameter to an API made by my back-end programmer, he told me that all i need to do is to send the one parameter to a given URL via POST using ajax.

The problem is I get a *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present* error.

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis) question and tried to implement the first answer's solution with no success. When i test the API via [hurl](https://www.hurl.it/) it works with no problem.

this is the code that i am using to send the form

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.btnEnviar').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://xxxxx.xxx/subscribers/subscribeEmail',
                datatype: 'jsonp',
                async: true,
                success:function(){
                    try{
                        alert("ok");
                    }catch (e){
                        alert(e);
                    }
                } 
            });                
        });
    });
```

And this is the form:

```
<form class="newsletter" method="post" action="http://xxxxx.xxx/subscribers/subscribeEmail">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="mail here!" class="input" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" class="send pull-right hidden" value="Subscribe me!" placeholder="Subscribe me!">
                    <span class="btnEnviar"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                </form>
```

there shouldn't be any PHP involved in the process.

Any insights on what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: if i send the form without ajax i get the correct response from the API so i'ts just a problem with my ajax script

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `crossDomain: true` and `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to the request:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.btnEnviar').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://xxxxx.xxx/subscribers/subscribeEmail',
            datatype: 'jsonp',
            async: true,
            xhrFields: {
               withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            success:function(){
                try{
                    alert("ok");
                }catch (e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            } 
        });                
    });
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: tried it, and get a net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED error

Comment: @user2770956 Probably because http://xxxxx.xxx isn't the real URL, but that's the one you gave in your question.

Comment: What an idiot. I fixed it but now i get the same error as before No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present.

Comment: The server side needs to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the response.  Tell your backend programmer to add that.

Comment: But if i try the API with hurl.it (it's another domain as well) it works properly