# Rails capybara feature spec No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a feature spec, as part of the page load. 
I hit a local url to get more data.

i.e. using http://fullcalendar.io/
which loads it's events via ajax

```
   events: {
             url: 'calendar_events.json',
             type: 'GET',
             error: function(response) {
             ...
            }},
```

I am getting

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/calendar_events.json?start=2014-01-20&end=2014-01-27. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Not exactly sure how to resolve. I tried adding

```
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
```

To a before_filter on my application controller just to see, but still get same issue.

NOTE: I am using capybara-webkit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6120260/3274024 you could check that out, maybe that is whats wrong with the request.

Comment: Don't really want to change it to jsonp

Comment: Maybe the cross domain trigger is enough. Not sure if I understand why you are hitting the local url, could you not just render it right away on server side?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to set these would be in your test environment, as you wouldn't want to open up origins in production.

**test.rb**

```
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!(
  {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age' => "1728000",
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' =>'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  })
```

As for your issue I suspect you are getting this error after 'save_and_open_page' in which case it is simply a rendering error based on your capybara asset_path and not the actual problem with your test case.

Comment: Do you know the way of setting the default headers for Rails 3?

Comment: For single requests its along the lines of:  "get desired_path, params_hash , { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*' }.   I suspect setting defaults didnt work for you as per above?

Comment: Yes, the default_headers is only available for Rails 4.