# jQuery - No Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors

I'd like to load a site from a different domain. I've already set headers through php in my header.php file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

I've searched around for the correct way to do the ajax request with cross domain enabled and ended up with this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: target,
    processData: true,
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data)
    {
        $("#toolsarea").attr('src', target);
    }
});
```

but I still get the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Is there still something I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error sending a jQuery Post to Google API's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to **Same origin policy** which prevent JavaScript to make an AJAX request for security reasons.

You need to make sure CORS is enabled on your PHP server.

You can do it using:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
```

More information on how to enable CORS on your server can be found here:

http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

You can read more about Same-origin policy on the client here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy