# Ajax/ASP.net Oauth2 for Wrike API v3

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, oauth

I've been trying to work with the Wrike API, but I am having trouble getting my access token using Ajax or ASP.Net. I am currently using the ["Wrike for Developers Documentation"](https://developers.wrike.com/documentation/oauth2), and this is my first time working with Oauth2. There aren't any JavaScript or ASP.net examples and I could only find projects on GitHub for node.js and PHP.

Here is the code I am using to try and get the access token:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/token",
    data: {
        client_id: <client_id>,//I took these details out for the post
        client_secret: <client_secret>,//I took these details out for the post
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: get("code")//from redirect URI
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response); // server response
    }
});
```

However I keep getting Error 400 (bad request). Is there anything obvious that I'm missing? Or is this not possible to do without doing the authentication server side using C#?

I hope this is enough information for you.  thanks in advance.

I also had cross origin issues that I think I solved with this post: [Cross Origin Stack Over Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis) Prior to that I used this as my code:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'Post',
  url: "https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/token",
  data: {
    client_id: "<client_id>",
    client_secret: <client_Secret>,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: get("code")
  },
  success: function (response) {
    alert(response); // server response
  }
});
```

I also tried this to fix my CORS issue but with no avail: [CORS on ASP.NET](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html)

Update:

I tried doing it via the ASP.net back end with C# I still get a error 400 bad request but when I take the request I made with it and put it into postman I am able to get the token. Here is the code I'm using. I'll update this question if I fix it completely.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    string ClientID = <ClientID>;
    string ClientSecret = <ClientSecret>;
    string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
    string.Format("https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={2}", ClientID, ClientSecret, code);

    if (Request["code"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format(
            "https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type=code",
            ClientID));
    }
    else
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        string url = string.Format("www.wrike.com/oauth2/token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={2}", ClientID, ClientSecret, code);
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
            {
                tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                    token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
            }
        }

        string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `jsonp` without specifing a callback? I will suggest get rid of corssDomain and change dataType to 'json'

Comment: I was using [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis) as a reference. And the result of changing jsonp to json and removing crossdomain gave me this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:59614' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: The reason you are having a Cross-domain issue is because you are posting a bad request, and you dont have the correct response header. I suspect there is something wrong with your post data. i recommend you to use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to investigate your request before putting it into ajax.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that and got this as my response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Authorization code is invalid"
} I copied the authorization code from my browser so that might be causing that problem. I don't tink I can get it from postman because it brings me to a login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys after a lot of time and effort I've found a solution. Rather than getting the access token using ajax and dealing with Cross Origin issues I decided to get the token via the back end C#. You will still need to parse the token var for the access token but that's easy to do. For reference the var token contains the information below ([Wrike API Oauth2 documentation](https://developers.wrike.com/documentation/oauth2)):

```
{
   "access_token": "2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "refresh_token": "tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ClientID = "<clientID>";
    string ClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>";
    string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
    string.Format("https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={2}", ClientID, ClientSecret, code);

    if (Request["code"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format(
            "https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type=code",
            ClientID));
    }
    else
    {
        string url = string.Format("https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={2}", ClientID, ClientSecret, code);
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request.Method = "Post";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            var token = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

This tutorial helped me out with creating the http request using ASP.Net:
[Post on Facebook User's wall using ASP.Net C#](http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Grant-Access-And-Post-As-Facebook-User-ASPNet)